# Memory Leak in Custom Linked List C++

Tags: c++, list, memory-leaks, valgrind

For an assignment I **cannot** use a STL list, it must be a custom list. As the title states, I have memory leaks even though I am calling delete on the nodes \ items. I would appreciate any help on this.

List Source

```
template <typename T>
class DLinkList
{
private:
    struct Node
    {
        T data;
        Node *nextNode;
        Node *prevNode;
        Node(T data, Node *nextNode = nullptr, Node *prevNode = nullptr)
        {
            this->data = data;
            this->nextNode = nextNode;
            this->prevNode = prevNode;
        }
        ~Node() { delete data; }
    };

    Node *head;
    Node *tail;

public:
    DLinkList();
    ~DLinkList();

    void push_back(T data);   
};

template <typename T>
inline void DLinkList<T>::push_back(T data)
{
    if (isEmpty())
    {
        head = new Node(data);
        tail = head;
    }
    else
    {
        tail->nextNode = new Node(data, nullptr, tail);
        tail = tail->nextNode;
    }
}

template <typename T>
DLinkList<T>::DLinkList()
{
    head = nullptr;
    tail = nullptr;
}

template <typename T>
DLinkList<T>::~DLinkList()
{
    Node *ptr = head;
    while (ptr->nextNode != nullptr)
    {
        Node *garbage = ptr;
        ptr = ptr->nextNode;
        delete garbage;
    }
}
```

Foo Class and main

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() { i = 0; d = 0.0; }
    Foo(int i, double d) { this->i = i; this->d = d; }

    int getInteger() { return i; }
    double getDouble() { return d; }

private:
    int i;
    double d;
};


int main()
{
    DLinkList<Foo*> f1;
    f1.push_back(new Foo());
    f1.push_back(new Foo(2, 5.5));

    cout << "1st Values: " << f1.at(0)->getInteger() << ", " << f1.at(0)->getDouble() << endl;
    cout << "2nd Values: " << f1.at(1)->getInteger() << ", " << f1.at(1)->getDouble() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

From valgrind

```
==12125== 40 (24 direct, 16 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 3 of 3
==12125==    at 0x4C29203: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:334)
==12125==    by 0x400FD8: DLinkList<Foo*>::push_back(Foo*) (DLinkList.hpp:138)
==12125==    by 0x400CF3: main (Source.cpp:28)
```

I am not sure how the memory is being lost here, I want to say that it is because it is making a copy of it and the original is being lost. If this is the case, I am unfamiliar with how to handle it.

Again, I appreciate any help in understanding this. I have tried to look through all related questions, but I did not see anything that covered this or at least I did not understand it. Thank you!

Comment: My guess is that it depends on what type you're using for `T`. Maybe a destructor in `Node` would help.

Comment: I just tried that. Called delete on data, valgrind shows  4 allocs, 4 frees - but I still have a leak with the same message.

Comment: @MasonR `f1.~DLinkList();` -- Why are you doing this?  Destructors for objects are called automatically once the object goes out of scope.  All you're doing here is causing memory corruption by interfering in the way C++ destructors work.  Get rid of that line, and fix your class so that it has correct copy semantics (your program is easily broken by simply assigning a `DLinkList` to another `DLInkList`).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I removed the line, I understand it is automatic. As far as making the class copyable, how might that fix the memory leak issue here?

Comment: You will run into memory leaks and double free issues again as soon as you do something like this: `DLinkList<foo*> f2 = f1;` after you've populated `f1`.  Second, removing that line may not correct all the memory leakage, but does address the memory corruption issues that come about by explicitly calling the destructor like that.

Comment: I can understand and appreciate that, thank you for the heads up. That is outside the scope of the assignment, but I will keep that in mind and implement it from now on. :)  --- Right, I still have the leak unfortunately.

Comment: Basically you need to implement a copy constructor and an assignment operator.  Also, note that you created a `DLinkList<foo*>` and put in that list, pointers that point to dynamically allocated in `main`.  So it is the responsibility of `main` to clean up those pointers, not `DLinkList`.  You have a separation of concerns issue, which is why you're getting memory leaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the other issues pointed out in the comments such as making an erroneous usage of explicitly calling the `DLinkList` destructor, you are doing this in `main()`:

```
f1.push_back(new Foo());
f1.push_back(new Foo(2, 5.5));
```

You are creating an instant memory leak here on those two lines of code that can not be recovered.  You are calling `new` but nowhere do you save the address returned from `new` so that you can call `delete` later on for that address.

So it is `main` that has to manage these dynamically allocated `Foo` objects.  Something like this:

```
Foo* p1 = new Foo();
Foo *p2 = new Foo(2, 5.5);
f1.push_back(p1);
f1.push_back(p2);
//...
delete p1;
delete p2;
```

This should address the memory leak, but this is poor programming practice in this day and age of C++.  You would more than likely either use

```
DLinkList<Foo>
```

and place `Foo` objects in the linked list, thus not requiring any manual memory management in `main`, or use a smart pointer and have a linked list of smart pointers, i.e.

```
DLinkList<std::unique_ptr<Foo>>
```

Comment: Thank you for the replies. I normally do use vectors and list and have main clean it up with a simple loop. I have tried it the first and second way, and for one reason or another, it still has the leak. I did not try it with smart pointers as I am not suppose to use those either :(

Comment: Please see below answer to explain how the memory leak was corrected. I still marked this one as the chosen answer because PaulMcKenzie brought up a lot of good points that also contributed to memory leaks. Thank you PaulMcKenzie!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I am just exhausted and was missing the simplest thing. After comparing to other lists I created, I realized that my destructor was not deleting the nodes correctly.

```
template <typename T>
DLinkList<T>::~DLinkList()
{
    Node *ptr = head;
    while (ptr != nullptr) // Not: ptr->nextNode
    {
        Node *garbage = ptr;
        ptr = ptr->nextNode;
        delete garbage;
    }
}
```

But I do want to thank PaulMcKenzie, was a great help and also pointed out that main does need to handle the deletion of the new calls. I will up vote his and mark it.